# Public variable Unity has a wrong value

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am new in Unity using C#. I have this code:

```
public class cerealkiller : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float moveUnit = 100.0f;

    void Start()
    {
        //QualitySettings.vSyncCount = 0;
        //Application.targetFrameRate = 24;
    }
    void moveMC()
    {
        Debug.Log("moveUnit original is: " + moveUnit);
        moveUnit = 4.0f;
        Debug.Log("moveUnit is: "+moveUnit);
        float horizontal = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
        float vertical = Input.GetAxis("Vertical");
        Vector2 position = transform.position;
        position.x = position.x + moveUnit * horizontal * Time.deltaTime;
        position.y = position.y + moveUnit * vertical * Time.deltaTime;
        transform.position = position;
    }
    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        moveMC();
    }
}
```

Initially I want to have a global variable for calculated how many unit the character move called `moveUnit`.

Problem that eventhough I already initialized the variable to 100.0f, in the `Update()` function it will always come out as 0.3f. As shown in the log below:

```
moveUnit original is: 0.3
moveUnit is: 4
```

Anyone can explain?

And if someone like Sir @Selvin here think that I have other code that changes the variable. Then you guessed it wrong, because currently this script is the only script I have.

Comment: You modify it from code which is not in your question ... with code like `cerealkillerInstance.moveUnit = 0.3f` or similar

Comment: @Selvin No, currently that one is the only script I have.

Comment: make moveUnit "Private" instead of "Public" to make sure you didn't set its value in the inspector or from another script.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`public float moveUnit = 100f` is serialized by default and tweakable in the Unity inspector, so make sure the value is actually set to 100 in the inspector.
I would set `moveUnit` to "Private" to make sure it's not being used by other scripts AND to make it non-serialized by default (unless you want that).

Then, make sure you don't set `moveUnit = 4.0f` if you want it to remain a single value.
If you want a *global* variable: I would look into the `static` keyword. If you want a value which doesn't change: I would consider the `readonly` or `const` keyword.

code examples:

```
//no risk of outside editing via the inspector or other scripts
private float moveUnit = 100.0f;
```

```
//global and non-editable
private static readonly float moveUnit = 100.0f;
```